# VBA implementing an interface with a custom class

Tags: vba

I just want to make sure.

I have a Class User with field ID and NAME. Next i have class RATE with field User as User. And finally i want to implement interface class Rate to next class RateStudent and RateTeacher.

it seems that I can't implement a class that contains custom fields because if I change the type of the user field to string everything is ok but if the user field in the Rate class is of type User then the debugger throws an error

**Class User**

```
Public id As Long
Public name As String
```

**Class Rate (interface)**

```
Public User As User
```

**Class RateStudent**

```
Implements Rate

Private m_User As User

Public Property Let Rate_User(ByVal value As User)
    Set m_User = value
End Property

Public Property Get Rate_User() As User
   Set Rate_User = m_User
End Property
```

And debugger error:

[image]

Comment: Please update your answer with the relevant code and where the error occurs along with the error message - difficult to help without them.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used it, but isn't it "Public Property Set" instead of "Public Property Let" for object variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with this code.

**1:** You gave variable name the same name as the type which will cause an error

```
Public User As User
```

Let's change the User class name to clsUser for this example and then we would change the **Rate** code to this

```
Public User As clsUser
```

**2:** The interface error is caused because you are using the **Let** property. You should use the **Set** property

```
Private Property Set rate_User(ByVal value As clsUser)
    Set m_User = value
End Property
```

An easy way to get this right is after you add the "Implements Rate" line you can select Rate from the left dropdown. Then properties will automatically appear in the right dropdown. You can select them from this dropdown and VBA will automatically add them.